# Cannot see an answer to my own question for which I received a notification

Tags: support, answers, bounties, notifications, deleted-answers

On December 20th I started a bounty (the very first bounty I have ever started) on my own question at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933728/how-to-write-nice-templates-in-jinja-and-nunjucks-when-indentation-level-matters) and then I went on holidays.

During the bounty period I would swear I received a notification that mentioned an answer (not a comment) to that question. At that time I was on holiday and I simply gave a quick glimpse at the answer (which essentially pointed me to another answer on Stack Overflow), but now that I want to read it carefully I do not see any answer under my question!

Has it been removed (why)? Does it have something to do with the fact that I didn't award the bounty before it ended? Is there any way to recover that answer?

Comment: Could it have been deleted meanwhile?

Comment: Could be... but is there any way to at least see that the answer has been delete? Maybe the reputation needed is higher than my current reputation on Stack Overflow (i.e. 582)?

Comment: _"but is there any way to at least see that the answer_" Not unless you have 10k+ rep.

Comment: Now that I see that your Stack Overflow reputation is 80k+ I think I will take your first comment more like a hint XD. Still, being the OP, I would really like to be able to read the content of that answer...

Comment: FWIW the answerer of the question [pointed you here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991479/jinja2-correctly-indent-included-block) as part of that deleted answer. Given that the answer was deleted that pointer may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

An answer was posted but then it was deleted by the poster a few hours later. It was downvoted so presumably someone else thought it wasn't a good answer and the poster then succumbed to that peer pressure.

There's not any reasonable way to recover the answer. If the poster doesn't think it's worth keeping around then we really shouldn't insist it exists. Hopefully someone else will come along and write a better answer at some point.

The only other way round this is if you get 10K rep you will be able to see all deleted answers to your questions.